# How to find the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a defined set in a measure space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,F,\mu)$ be a measure space. Find the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{E \in F : \mu(E) = 0\}$ in the cases that $μ$ is finite and when it isn't. With my definition of a measure I deduced that as $μ(∅)=0$, $E=∅$ hence the $σ$-algebra will only admit $∅$ as an element. I assumed my answer to be incorrect however as I deduced this independent of $μ$ being finite or not and also as I'm very unfamiliar with $σ$-algebras. Where do I go from here?

Comment: It would be interesting to see your approach to this problem !

Comment: @Hamdiken Very well, with my definition of a measure I deduced that as μ(∅)=0, E=∅ hence the σ-algebra will only admit ∅  as an element. However I assumed my answer to be incorrect as I deduced this independent of μ being finite or not and also as I'm very unfamiliar with σ-algebras. My apologies if it seems I've put no thought into this, I'm simply quite confused.

Comment: The first thing one learns about a $\sigma$-algebra is that when a set $A$ is in it then also its complement $\Omega\setminus A$ is in it. Can then $\{\emptyset\}$ possibly be a $\sigma$-algebra ?

Comment: @KurtG. Okay so I'm incorrect, as I expected, what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Take the axioms of $\sigma$-algebra (there are not that many) and ask yourself what other sets must be included. Don't ask for spoon feeding.

Comment: @KurtG. I understand that it seems to you that I'm putting in little effort however I'm struggling with this particular module that I'm only a couple weeks into and am asking for very specific help, if I need 'spoon-feeding' I will very well ask for it. If you don't like the nature of my question, report it and leave it alone.

Comment: Apologies. Candidates of sets I would include into the $\sigma$-algebra are $\Omega$, all $\mu$-null sets, and all their complements. Can you check if any sets are missing or if that makes it a $\sigma$-algebra ?

Comment: @KurtG. no need to apologise, I'm starting to grasp what this question is asking a lot better now thanks to you. As the complements are also μ -null sets this implies E consists of all co-negligible sets i.e. the measure space is complete. Hence our σ -algebra is the σ -algebra such that (X,F, μ) is complete. Also, surely it must be irrelevant that we assume μ is finite as we know  μ(E)=0?

Comment: Not quite. Let's first concentrate on the case that $\mu$ is finite. WLOG $\mu(X)=1$. If $E$ is a $\mu$-null set its complement $X\setminus E$ has what measure ? Surely not $0$.

Comment: @KurtG. well no that relative complement describes two disjoint sets, hence X\E=X which would mean this complement has  measure 1, which would that mean that the sigma algebra we're looking for is non-existent in the  context that  μ is finite, however surely this would imply the same thing if  μ wasn't finite.

Comment: I can assure you that that $\sigma$-algebra is existent.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\mu$ is finite. WLOG $\mu(X)=1$. Let's look at the collection $\cal A$ of sets that consists of

- all $\mu$-null sets $E$ in ${\cal F}$
- the complements $X\setminus E$ of all $\mu$-null sets $E$ in $\cal F$.

***Claim.*** *${\cal A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.*

*Proof*.

1. When $\mu(E)=0$ then $\mu(X\setminus E)=1$.
2. When $E_1,E_2,...$ is a countable collection of $\mu$-null sets then $\mu(\bigcup_n E_n)\le \sum_n\mu(E_n)=0\,.$ Therefore $\bigcup_n E_n\in{\cal A}\,.$
3. When $E_1,E_2$ are two $\mu$-null sets then
   $$
   \mu(E_1\cup X\setminus E_2)=\underbrace{\mu(E_1\setminus (X\setminus E_2))}_{\le\,\mu(E_1)\,=\,0}+\underbrace{\mu(X\setminus E_2)}_{=1}=1
   $$
   therefore, the complement of $E_1\cup X\setminus E_2$ is a $\mu$-null set. In other words, this set is in ${\cal A}$.
4. When $A_1,A_2,...$ is a countable collection of sets in ${\cal A}$ where either
   $A_i$ is a $\mu$-null set or $X\setminus A_i$ is a $\mu$-null set then
   $$
   \bigcup_n A_n=\bigcup_k E_k \cup \bigcup_m (X\setminus E_m)\,.
   $$
   We know that $\bigcup_k E_k$ is a $\mu$-null set and it is clear that
   $\mu(\bigcup_m (X\setminus E_m))=1\,.$ Therefore, $\bigcup_m (X\setminus E_m)$ is the complement of a $\mu$-null set. By point 3. $\bigcup_n A_n\in\cal A\,.$

Can you finish ?

$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$